# What is the maximum bounty one can provide?

Tags: discussion

What is the maximum number of points one can leave as a bounty?

Comment: Whats the Question Joe, save your bounty rep, I'll answer it for free.

Comment: I was just curious more than anything.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, I was just trying to break my downvote record :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can leave a maximum of 500 points for a single bounty, according to the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). The page also says that you could offer multiple bounties on the same question (only one at a time though).

However, there doesn't seem to be any restriction on the number of times you could offer a bounty on one question (after the previous one is inactive, of course), so you could technically give away *all* your reputation, although *in your case* that would take a loooooong time. :-)

Comment: I believe that each time you offer a bounty on the same question you need to increase it, so he can't give away 100k in bounties on a single question. :-)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Does that mean you can't offer further bounties after 500, or that they keep increasing above the cap (600, 700 800 etc.)?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I thought the doubling of bounty is subject to the ceiling of 500, not sure where I read that.

Comment: [A bounty has to be twice your last bounty on that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281920/162102), minimum, and 500 is the maximum bounty amount.  So if you want to maximize your beneficence, I think the best you can do is 50-100-250-500.