# Cannot give more than one bounty per question

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

I recently asked a question that gave me some rep points and I want to invest all those points on this [answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/116027/100602)

I had 450+ rep, started a bounty and rewarded that answer and now that I have again 100+ I want to give it away on the same answer, but [I no longer have the "Start bounty"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZCcZ.png) button available on the question.

Why is that so? Is it a bug? Is there some cool-down period that I need to wait?

According to [this other question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4148/what-is-the-maximum-bounty-one-can-provide) I should be able to give a bounty on the same question multiple times.

Comment: I always have a hard time finding the bounty button - it's actually *below* the comments, not above. Are you sure it's not there?

Comment: You've already awarded two bounties on this answer totalling 700 rep points.  I think you can safely say that you've thanked this user enough now.

Comment: I do agree with @Snow. Why are you so dead-set on giving all of your rep to that particular answer? Whether it's true or not, it very much makes it *look* like your "AnonOP" account is just a sock account for Ertai87, and you are just trying to funnel rep back to your main account.

Comment: @DavidK To me it reads more like the OP here is very grateful to the advice given because it lead him to make the right choice in his career. It illustrates the tremendous impact that our answers can have on this site. @ OP: FWIW I've contributed a 300 rep bounty to this answer.

Comment: @Lilienthal thanks! that's exactly the right reason for why I (try to) spend all my reputation on that answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Quoted in part:

> **Can I offer a second bounty after the first one has expired? / Can I raise my bounty?**
>
> You can offer as many bounties on a question as you want. However, only one bounty can be active on a question at a time. Moreover, any user may have at most 3 concurrent bounties.
>
> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, you will have to double the amount each time (or more). That is, if your first bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200 and so on. If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as you like (or as long as you have the rep). This doubling applies only to bounties by the same user on the same question.

So you'll need to offer up twice the amount of your last bounty payment, up to the maximum of 500.

Comment: Learned something new today!

Comment: I see just now that I can't start a bounty on any question... why is that?

Comment: @AnonOP You should be able to offer bounties on other questions. Make sure you are looking in the right place - the screenshot you link in your question is *not* the right location. The button is located below all of the comments, not above. [Here's a Meta request to move it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234095/can-we-move-start-a-bounty-to-a-more-intuitive-location).